Domain name not properly migrated from Google Domains after Squarespace acquisition
My client said she bought a google domain. As we know Google has moved domain names to Square Space! SquareSpace emailed her and said "[redacted_name].com is now available on your Squarespace Domains account". I redacted the name but you get it. She logged in just like it told her but there are no domains in her account. What to do to fix it?

I'd contact Squarespace support, as they might be able to get back to you with a good answer more quickly than this community can. If it's something that's affecting many customers, you could even post an answer here once you've got it resolved.
